# Why does Android 8.1 not see resources?

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-8.1-oreo

I updated my phone to android 8.1 and launched my app. I noticed the strange error - "resources not found". In android 7.1 everything works well. I've already tried to clean and rebuild project. I think the code below should be enough to find an error.

SplashActivity style

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

bakcground_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".splash.SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="music.pl"
            android:pathPrefix="/music" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.linkplayer.linkplayer/com.linkplayer.linkplayer.splash.SplashActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.linkplayer.linkplayer:drawable/background_splash with resource ID #0x7f07005e
```

Thanks in advance for the help. Have a nice evening.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue. Have you tried a fresh installation?

Comment: Same code on Android 7.1 works and on Android 8.1 not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in this part of xml:

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</item>
```

I don't know why but Android 8.0+ can't see mipmaps. I had to use file from "drawable" directory:

```
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/my_drawable"/>
</item>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Still up to date (android 8.0.1)
You can try this. build.gradle
android {

```
bundle {
    density {
        enableSplit = false
    }

    abi {
        enableSplit = false
    }

    language {
        enableSplit = false
    }
}
```

...
}